# C++ Use an object in another class

Tags: c++

I'm pretty new to c++. Any help would be appreciated.
So in the Presentation class, I have an object called m_metricRecorder, declared like this:

```
Presentation::Presentation(std::shared_ptr<metrics::MetricRecorderInterface> metricRecorder):
m_metricRecorder{metricRecorder} {}
```

I wanna use m_metricRecorder in another class. How to do that? I've included the Presentation class. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it depends on how you want to use it.

One possibility is to write a getter

```
std::shared_ptr<metrics::MetricRecorderInterface> Presentation::getMetricRecorder()
{
    return m_metricRecorder;
}
```

Whether that's the best solution for you depends on details you haven't said.

**EDIT**
Further to what po.pe said, I am taking for granted that you know you need an instance of your `Presentation` class in order to use the getter above.

Comment: Hi John, thank you very much for your response.
I am still a bit confused. So for the getter, should I implement it in the Presentation class or the other class? 
Aslo for adding an instance, could you give me more information of how to do it?
Sorry I am pretty new to C++. Thank you!

Comment: In the `Presentation` class (that's why I have written `Presentation::getMetricRecorder`). How you get an instance of your `Presentation` class is only something you can answer because only you can see your code. All I meant by that was that since the metric recorder object is inside the presentation object the first thing you need to access the metric recorder object is a presentation object. That may be completely obvious to you, or it may not. The getter is a way of getting from a `Presentation` object to a `MetricRecorderInterface` object, but first you need the `Presentation` object.

Answer (score 0):

Your other class needs to have an instance or a reference to an instance of the `Presentation` class. Or it could be derived from the `Presentation` class but I think that's not what you want.

Comment: There's a little thing called accessibility too.